# How do I make code run on the Pi from Python

Tags: python

The code I'd like to run is this on the Pi from Python:

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 192.168.0.1 netmask 255.255.255.0
```

should I use `os.system` or `subprocess` or something?

an example of what I want is here:

```
var1 = self.controller.internet_inet_value.get()
        var2 = self.controller.internet_mask_value.get()


var = subprocess.Popen(['sudo', 'ifconfig', 'eth1', '%s' % 
   self.controller.internet_inet_value.get(), 'netmask', '%s'
   self.controller.internet_mask_value.get()])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use subprocess it is prefered for more complex things

```
import subprocess

var = subprocess.Popen(['sudo', 'ifconfig', 'eth1', self.controller.internet_inet_value.get(), 'netmask', self.controller.internet_mask_value.get()],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)


output = var.communicate()[0]
```